# R Filling empty data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks the following way.

```
     Q      C       N
     2      234     white
     3      888     white
     4      543     white
     5      234     white
     1      098     Blue
     3      126     Blue
     5      366     Black
     1      222     pink
     2      897     pink
```

i want the data frame to look like this.

```
     Q      C       N
     1      555     white
     2      234     white
     3      888     white
     4      543     white
     5      234     white
     1      098     Blue
     2      0       Blue
     3      126     Blue
     4      0       Blue
     5      0       Blue
     1      0       Black
     2      0       Black
     3      0       Black
     4      0       Black
     5      366     Black
     1      222     pink
     2      897     pink  
     3      0       pink
     4      0       pink
     5      0       pink
```

I want it to appear like this.
The idea is that Q always has to be from 1-5 if it doesn't appear i want the data frame to have a line were the quality is the one that is missing with its name and fill 0 for the C.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df, Q, N, fill = list(C = 0))
```

Gets what you want (assuming your data is called `df`). It reorders the columns and rows, but you can sort that out if necessary.

---

Using this data as input:

```
df <- structure(list(Q = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L), C = c(234L, 
888L, 543L, 234L, 98L, 126L, 366L, 222L, 897L), N = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Black", "Blue", 
"pink", "white"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Q", "C", "N"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df
#   Q   C     N
# 1 2 234 white
# 2 3 888 white
# 3 4 543 white
# 4 5 234 white
# 5 1  98  Blue
# 6 3 126  Blue
# 7 5 366 Black
# 8 1 222  pink
# 9 2 897  pink

complete(df, Q, N, fill = list(C = 0))
# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#        Q      N     C
#    <int> <fctr> <dbl>
# 1      1  Black     0
# 2      1   Blue    98
# 3      1   pink   222
# 4      1  white     0
# 5      2  Black     0
# 6      2   Blue     0
# 7      2   pink   897
# 8      2  white   234
# 9      3  Black     0
# 10     3   Blue   126
# 11     3   pink     0
# 12     3  white   888
# 13     4  Black     0
# 14     4   Blue     0
# 15     4   pink     0
# 16     4  white   543
# 17     5  Black   366
# 18     5   Blue     0
# 19     5   pink     0
# 20     5  white   234
```

Comment: Holy moly, I love `dplyr` and `tidyr`, but I didn't know `complete` until now :-) I used to do `bleh %>% merge(bleh %>% group_by(a,b) %>% summarise(), all = T) %>% replace_na(list(c = 0))`, wich essentially does the same (I suppose, slower)

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this in `base R` with `expand.grid` and `merge`

```
transform(merge(expand.grid(Q= unique(df$Q), N = unique(df$N)), 
               df, all.x=TRUE), C = replace(C, is.na(C), 0))
#   Q     N   C
#1  1 Black   0
#2  1  Blue  98
#3  1  pink 222
#4  1 white   0
#5  2 Black   0
#6  2  Blue   0
#7  2  pink 897
#8  2 white 234
#9  3 Black   0
#10 3  Blue 126
#11 3  pink   0
#12 3 white 888
#13 4 Black   0
#14 4  Blue   0
#15 4  pink   0
#16 4 white 543
#17 5 Black 366
#18 5  Blue   0
#19 5  pink   0
#20 5 white 234
```